# Firestore in Datastore Emulator - Transaction contention

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

In order for multiple developers to develop locally without interfering with each other, we want to use the datastore emulator provided by Google Cloud. Unfortunately, we are experiencing quite different behavior with the emulator compared to the actual Datastore which makes it impossible to run locally.

Issue: We are running two transactions that perform the exact same set of operations.
In each transaction, we make a simple equality query on a field called `field`. In each transaction, the value for the lookup is a randomly generated string. Then after making the lookup, we save a new entity whose `field` equals the value used to lookup. If we perform more than one transaction using the **emulator** (with flag `--use-firestore-in-datastore-mode`), `n >= 2`,  we get a transaction contention error. On the other hand, if we perform the same test using an instance of Datastore in GCP, we do not get any errors and all transactions complete successfully. Even when performing 1000 test transactions multiple times, we observed no issues.

**Test code (NodeJS):**

```js
const datastore = new Datastore(); 
const kind  = "TEST"; //Entity kind for testing

async function main() 
{
    const n = 2; //Number of test transactions

    const promises = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++)
        promises.push(doTestTransaction(i));
    await Promise.all(promises);

}



async function doTestTransaction(i : number)
{
    try
    {
        const field = Random.getGlobalIdentifier(); //Generates a random ID using nanoid
        const transaction = datastore.transaction();
        await transaction.run();
        await transaction.runQuery(transaction.createQuery(kind).filter("field", "=", field).select("__key__").limit(1));
        transaction.save({key: datastore.key([kind, Random.getGlobalIdentifier()]), data: {field}})
        await transaction.commit();
    
    }
    catch(err)
    {
        console.log("ERROR : ", err)
    }

    
}

main();
```

Is there any workaround to this issue? One would not expect such a discrepancy between the emulator and the actual product.

Comment: Are you using the default configuration of the datastore, or are you using the "datastore in Firestore" mode?

Comment: I forgot to mention that! Yes, we are using the `--use-firestore-in-datastore-mode` flag when running the emulator.